# How do I install manually a package instead using yum

Tags: centos, yum

My issue is simple, I have to install this lib:

```
yum install libyaml-devel
```

As I'm working for a company which has some stupid security rules, I can't install it using yum.

I would like to know where `yum` download the package `libyaml-devel` and install it myself.

Comment: Don't duplicate questions. You've re-asked essentially the same question as https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276727/4671

Comment: That question is related to libyaml libraries and here I'm used it as an example. This question is related to yum and how it works. TY for your help in both questions

Answer (score 0):

yum use /etc/yum.repos.d repository for software install,
you can add your own repository into it..

use rpm command to install individual package instead of yum.
(for RedHat / Fedora / etc)

Where yum downloaded packages
for example, using fedora
/var/cache/yum/x86_64/21/fedora/packages